# MySQL Syntax Of Complex Sub Calculation

Tags: php, mysql, select, syntax, proc

Using the following select I am trying to look at each row as the PHP cycles through it, pull current location radius and work out the distance from each 'event' to that current location using a PROC `distance_between` then populate `DISTANCEFROMEVENT` before moving to the next line.

Where I am falling down (as most of this works) is adding the action

```
distance_between 52.5960 , -1.9110 ,
GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE ,
GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LONGITUDE AS DISTANCEFROMEVENT
```

I'm not clear on the syntax off how I join this to the `SELECT` statement although I do know on its own it should work.

```
SELECT * FROM Current
    WHERE (GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE <53.319589001447
    AND
    GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE > 51.872410998553
    AND
    GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LONGITUDE > -2.6349916029658
    AND
    GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LONGITUDE < -1.1870083970342
    AND
    VALIDPERIOD_STARTOFPERIOD < '12-05-06 16:15:31'
    AND
    VALIDPERIOD_ENDOFPERIOD > '12-05-06 16:15:31' ,
    distance_between 52.5960 , -1.9110 , GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE , GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LONGITUDE AS DISTANCEFROMEVENT )
```

Any guidance I can get would be appreciated.

Terran

```
CREATE FUNCTION distance_between (from_lat DECIMAL(6, 3),
    from_lng DECIMAL(6, 3),
    to_lat DECIMAL(6, 3),
    to_lng DECIMAL(6, 3))
    RETURNS DECIMAL(11, 3)

    RETURN 6371 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(POW(SIN(RADIANS(to_lat - from_lat)/2), 2) +
    POW(SIN(RADIANS(to_lng - from_lng)/2), 2) * COS(RADIANS(from_lat)) *
    COS(RADIANS(to_lat))), SQRT(1 - POW(SIN(RADIANS(to_lat - from_lat)/2), 2) +
    POW(SIN(RADIANS(to_lng - from_lng)/2), 2) * COS(RADIANS(from_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(to_lat))));
```

Working.............

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.5960) ) * cos( radians( GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE ) ) * cos( radians( GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LONGITUDE ) - radians(-1.9110) ) + sin( radians(52.5960) ) * sin( radians( GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE ) ) ) ) AS DISTANCEFROMEVENT FROM Current HAVING DISTANCEFROMEVENT < 50 ORDER BY DISTANCEFROMEVENT
```

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this in the SQL query? It seems you could get the data, process it with PHP, and move on.

Comment: Hi - I'm trying to produce one final SQL set of data to present to a JSONP feature I have. In the xml version I simply ran the calculations for each line as it iterated though and then presented them when I was ready as the text was been created. As the JSONP call takes the SQL result I needed to do all the processing with in a single SQL query.....

Comment: Could you not do your calculations and store the result in a string/array/object that gets passed to the JSONP call?

Comment: When you say that do you mean my distance results or the SQL + distance results ? As I am still feeling my way I'm trying not to over complicate things yet hence was looking at simply the SQL side as the JSONP is consistent through out the rest of my coding.

Comment: SQL+distance results. You could do the SQL without distance, do the distance calculation (in php), and then modify the resulting rows with that distance, and finally pass the modified result set to your JSONP function.

Comment: Brendon - sounds good but not 100% confident in array manipulation which is why I went down this route. Reasearching still and thought I had an answer.... stuck it at the top - how ever its reporting a sql syntax, I need to have a good look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your last search term before the part that's giving you trouble is missing a closing "'". Unless that's just a typo on here. If that's not it, let me know and I'll take another look

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT *, (distance_between 52.5960 , -1.9110 , 
GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE , GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LONGITUDE) AS DISTANCEFROMEVENT 
FROM Current WHERE
GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE < 53.319589001447
AND GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE > 51.872410998553
AND GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LONGITUDE > -2.6349916029658
AND GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LONGITUDE < -1.1870083970342
AND VALIDPERIOD_STARTOFPERIOD < '12-05-06 16:15:31'
AND VALIDPERIOD_ENDOFPERIOD > '12-05-06 16:15:31'
```

Ok so you need to be calling the DISTANCEFROMEVENT field in the SELECT to get it to come up.

Comment: Yes - I think that was a copy/paste typo as I have been trying different ways of doing this - should be correct now. Added the PHP in as well in case that is of interest.

Comment: Alright I'm actually on my computer now instead of my phone. I don't recognize 'distance_between' as any kind of MySQL command and it comes right in on your WHERE clause and doesn't really make sense. Are you only trying this in php? or can you interface MySQL directly via command line or workbench to get the error number? Or doing it directly in php with mysql_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysql_errno($connect) . ": " . mysql_error($connect));

Comment: Hi - added the distance_between PROC above. The WHERE is asking for any data items that are within an area which is determined before calling the sql. Where most people do this with in the SQL code using a Haversine forumular I have gone for a straight box as its quick and the data will be shown on a screen. All this does work as I'm using it else where all the time.... ( and in fact I did this in php in about 5 mins )..... where I am falling down is adding the distance_between in as a sub action so I can dynamically work out the distance for each row from the center location.

Comment: The current user location is $latitude $longitude which you see above in the SQL query as a lat long. Also keys like GOFL_LOCCGRP_TPEGILOC_TO_POINTCOORDINATES_LATITUDE are my own custom columns with in the data base.

Comment: Just a quick note that I have edited above.... the last solution I proposed was working just had to tweak a couple of things. A big thanks to Brendon and Scarcrow.